# Teleport Command not working following Minecraft update?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have no idea why this is happening, but after the Command update that Minecraft has had, all of my command blocks have basically been nullified on my server, and I can't make them work as how everyone says.

For example, I have a lobby that has a room that you push a button. The nearest player will be teleported to the next room and bang, that's how it supposed to work.

```
tp @p 244 9 50
```

That is what it's been for most of its existence, and it worked. But now, for some reason; as well on many of my other command blocks, it think that the first code is a player, and therefore doesn't read it.

```
[17:21:59] Error: Player not found.
```

So I've tried many different ways to fix this; none of which have successfully worked.
I've put them in square brackets and such, and still nothing has worked! Someone please help me.

Other things I recall trying.

```
tp @p 244,9,50
tp @p [x=244,y=9,z=50]
tp target[@p] location[x=244,y=9,z=50]
tp @p <244 9 50>
tp @p[x=223,y=8,z=501] [x=244,y=9,z=50]
```

Comment: The first command you're using should work fine. Using any mods that mess with commands? Spigot+essentials is often the culprit for things like this

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, I always recommend looking up commands in the Minecraft wiki. The other syntaxes you've tried all have nothing to do with correct Minecraft command syntax, except for the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tp, from what it looks like, should be working, but if not there might be something else you could try, such as adding execute.

```
execute positioned ~ ~ ~ run tp @p 244 9 50
```

You can also do:

```
execute as @p run tp @s 244 9 50
```

If those don't work make sure commands are enabled on your server.

Comment: The execute should not be needed. The default execution location is from the command block that's running the command.

Comment: Keyword: should. I know that's usually the case, but because it isn't working for him I thought maybe he's doing something differently, and an alternative might be needed. I hope my edit made that a bit more clear, I think I forgot exactly what his case was for a moment.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked instantly; although I'll try my best to find a way to shorten it!

Comment: @EpikBerm you're welcome! I'd say the shortest way to use execute is to just use /execute run. Sorry your original commands didn't work though.